# Configparser How to Use a URL?

Tags: python, configparser

i try to creat a config.ini file i inserted this and want to read it and write this inside a variable for curl and for getting a name of the device

```
Config.ini
[DEFAULT]
#only default infos DONT CHANGE
DevicenameDEFAULT = NameoftheDevice
TGtokenCurlDEFAULT = TokenUrlforCUrltoTelegram

[DeviceInfo]
#change here your settings
Devicename = miniforum1-titty
TGtokenCurl = https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxx&text=
```

and want to use this with a variable

```
Geraet =
TGtoken =
```

and use the TGtoken inside this code:

```
def CurlExeptionErrorAccours():
    sleep(2)
    subprocess.call(['curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-d',
    'flow_x',
    (TGtoken,'ExeptionErrorAccours_',Geraet)])
    #Time for Timestamps
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Curl ExeptionErrorAccours", timenow)
    sleep(1)
    pass
```

and my script (function) looks like this:

```
import configparser

configini = configparser.ConfigParser()     
configini.read("scr\config\config.ini")
#show and print
Device_Name = configini.get('DeviceInfo', 'Devicename')
print(Device_Name)
TGtoken = Device_Name
```

is it right like this or should i use

```
TGtoken = configini.get('DeviceInfo', 'Devicename')
```

Comment: Btw, do not use subprocess + curl. Use real python http client library like urllib

Comment: I don't really understand your question. `TGtoken = Device_Name` is unnecessary line of code

Comment: so this is better : TGtoken = configini.get('DeviceInfo','TGtokenCurl')

Comment: Variable names do not matter as long as you use them consistently. That's a url, not a token, so I suggest you don't give it a name of `TGtoken`.

Comment: why i should use urllib? i copied the code from other script the use use this so i have used it to. do you have a  turorial for urllib?

Comment: Doesn't matter that you copied. This is not how you make http requests with Python. See docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request

Comment: i try to send telegram message to my bot when something happens inside script that is what i want to do

Answer (score 1):

Configparser only uses strings. URL is just a String.

You seem to be simply be asking about variables. So, first I suggest you use parameters

```
def CurlExeptionErrorAccours(url, Geraet):
    subprocess.call(['curl',  # however, you should replace this with native python http client call 
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-d',
    'flow_x',
    (url,'ExeptionErrorAccours_',Geraet)])
    # TODO: you should check the exit code of this command for failures
```

Then

```
import configparser

configini = configparser.ConfigParser()     
configini.read("scr\config\config.ini")
#show and print
url = configini.get('DeviceInfo', 'TGtokenCurl')
Geraet = configini.get('DeviceInfo', 'Devicename') # German translation? Why not put Geraet as config key? 
CurlExeptionErrorAccours(url, Geraet)
```

Comment: thanks but there is a problem with the url it works with the devicename and prints correct alsow it prints the url correct but if i use url inside the subprocess.call it dosnt send me the telegram message maybe it is blocked from system or the url have a \n or something in. is there a way to see what the cmd does? its to fast to see whats happen

Comment: i try this on one pc it works on the other my homepc i get : curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

Comment: Curl errors have nothing to do with Python. As mentioned, you should really use urllib. I don't recognize that error, anyway. Why not use an actual bot library? https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Introduction-to-the-API

Comment: thats  worked i  use TGtoken = configini.get('DeviceInfo', 'Devicename') and it  work  . but not  for  win32 api  to check  a  pixelmatchcolor  this i have  to  hard code inside the  script  it want work if  i  use configpaser and past it inside the code. win32 return -1 error

Comment: Please open a new post for any new errors you're getting as they are unrelated to your original question about `configparser`. As mentioned, configparser only has strings, so is not causing your errors.